# Use .htaccess to limit access to file downloads

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have downloads for static files like product.exe. I want to limit access
to these files with a .htaccess file so that only certain users can download it.

I think this can be handled with mod_rewrite and I found this snippet online 
that blocks bad sites using the referrer.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http://example.com/downloads/confirm/3811 [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Source: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess14.shtml

Instead of blocking based on referrer, I want to allow based on referrer. That way, the referrer can be a URL that cannot be accessed without first logging in. I am thinking about going this route and using the http referrer to give permission to the file. I know it may not be the best way to do it, and I guess the referrer can be spoofed, but it does not have to be THAT secure. I am also open to other ideas you may have to for limitting access.

Comment: What about using a scripting language like PHP or Perl to handle user validation and feeding the file to the browser?

Comment: @cdhowie - that is what we are currently doing, but the downloads are failing a lot for slower connections because we are using php to do a readfile. We want to do a direct download instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow based on Referrer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://goodsite-1.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://goodsite-2.com/from/there.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ # There are some users/browsers not sending referrer..
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

---

Or you can allow based on a cookie, which you can set before with e.g. PHP:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*cookie-name.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

---

Or also only allow Post requests:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

and your Link for 'post request' in your HTML to the file to download:

```
<form method="post" action="path/to/download.mp3">
  <input type="submit" value="Click here to download!" />
</form>
```

---

Actually you could combine these methods.

Comment: Actually, I tried using the http referrer, but IE doesn't give the http referrer. I read the IE docs and it said it doesn't give the referrer on non-SSL pages, but those docs might be old because it still doesn't work. So instead, I set a cookie in PHP like you suggested and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some security matters http_referrer is not a reliable header.

- Some browser configurations cause an empty http_referrer header
- There are tools that you can manipulate http request headers. You can take a look at Firefox developer tools.(Ctrl + Shift + I > Network)