# restrict file download php

Tags: php, authorization, download

I have this in my code:

```
<a href = "res/pdf/sample.pdf">Sample PDF</a>
```

So basically it will appear to be a download link to file 'sample.pdf' but the problem is, there's a restriction in downloading this file. so whenever there are confidential reports uploaded and a malicious user accidentally memorized or viewed the URL of the download link in the browser history he can easily download it even without accessing the website because it is a direct link. What am i supposed to do so this link will be protected? or be downloaded only for the user assigned to it?

Comment: i think you can find solution using htaccess..

Comment: how am i going to do with that htaccess?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Protecting digital Downloads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412328/php-protecting-digital-downloads)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't serve up files by their direct URLs. Have a PHP script receive the filename of the file wanted, and serve it up.

So, if someone wants to download the above files, he would go to

`example.com/getfile?file=sample.pdf`

Your PHP script would check if the current user has permission to view the file, and then serve it up.

Make your links like this:

```
<a href = "http://example.com/getfile?file=sample.pdf">Sample PDF</a>
```

Your current method is very insecure for sensitive files. A malicious user could trivially write a script to download ALL files in `res/pdf`. All he needs to do is check every permutation of letters in the directory, and throw away all 404 errors.

You will not redirect the user since that would defeat the purpose. You will serve the file as a download with the appropriate `Content-disposition` header.

Here's an example: [Fastest Way to Serve a File Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697748/fastest-way-to-serve-a-file-using-php)

You can google and get many more examples.

Here's a great example that shows how to serve PDF files:
https://serverfault.com/questions/316814/php-serve-a-file-for-download-without-providing-the-direct-link

Comment: so whenever I use this method. basically, there will be a redirection on the getfile.php. so on that getfile.php the URL will still be change?? can you please give me some example manipulation on the script where I will pass this GET values. I'm sorry I'm a noob

Comment: Sure, but I don't see how it's "trivial" to download all files of a given directory unless the files are listed when accessing the directory directly. You seem to underestimate the amount of file name permutations.

Comment: One would just have to check for every permutation as a filename in that directory. This process could easily be parallelized and run for a few days. I'd say that's pretty trivial if the directory stores corporate secrets.

Comment: @Juhana: I appreciate the amount of file name permutations, but if the data is valuable enough, one could easily rent some cloud computing time and have thousands of parallel threads run simultaneously.

Comment: Let's say the file names are max 20 characters long and they have letters both upper and lower case and some punctuation, 70 different characters in total, and you can check 1000 file names per second. These are all very generous assumptions. Even then, checking all permutations would take about 2.53^26 years - the age of the universe is about 13.7^9 years. Even checking 10 character long names with 40 different characters (case insensitive) would take 332,500 years.

Comment: @Juhana: You do have a point. Perhaps its not trivial to get ALL files, but it is very possible to get SOME files, which can be pretty bad as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict using htaccess

Comment: like how? can you please give me example. Thanks

Comment: You can check the HTTP_REFERER, 
check out the similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654944/use-htaccess-to-limit-access-to-file-downloads

Comment: this seems more like a comment than an answer